# Z-index issue. Welcome message at the center of the Bootsrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, z-index, navbar

I want to use the bootstrap navbar and I want to display a Welcome message at the center of the navbar. I do this into HTML: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/22779/

```css
@import url('https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css');

body{
  padding-top: 87px;
}
```

```html
<nav  class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">   
    <button class="hamburger hamburger--collapse hamburger--accessible js-hamburger" type="button">
        <span class="hamburger-box">
            <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
        </span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#home" id="menuhome">Accueil</a></li>
            <li><a href="#osteo" id="menuosteo">L'ostéopathie</a></li>
            <li><a href="#parcours" id="menuparcours">Mon parcours</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact" id="menucontact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="welcome">
    <h1>Bienvenue</h1>
</div>
```

But the welcome message never display. If I put a high z-index to the welcome class there is issue with the hamburger menu... How can I get ride of this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes but I want my welcome message in the middle of the navbar, not under..

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. Can you post an example of what you've tried so far because it seems like if it's always in the center of your navbar it will interfere with your links as well depending on the viewport size.

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/22779/ . I want the "Bienvenue" message in the middle of the navbar...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 2nd version

[image: the result]

We can't put a div outside of the navbar and place this div between the navbar and its items because of [the different stacking contexts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context):

> Each stacking context is completely independent from its siblings: only descendant elements are considered when stacking is processed.

So we have to put the `welcome` block inside the navbar at the very beginning of its. And we don't need to use `z-index` in this case.

Please check the result: https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/4baoqn6p/

```css
@import url('https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css');

body{
  padding-top: 87px;
}

.welcome {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
}
.welcome h1 {
  color: #555;
  font-weight: 900;
  line-height: 50px; /* = height of navbar */
  margin: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .hamburger {
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: #ccc; 
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">   
    <div class="welcome">
        <h1>Bienvenue</h1>
    </div>
    <button class="hamburger hamburger--collapse hamburger--accessible js-hamburger" type="button">
        <span class="hamburger-box">
            <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
        </span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#home" id="menuhome">Accueil</a></li>
            <li><a href="#osteo" id="menuosteo">L'ostéopathie</a></li>
            <li><a href="#parcours" id="menuparcours">Mon parcours</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact" id="menucontact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

### 1st version

1. The `.navbar-fixed-top` class has the `z-index: 1030;` porperty. So `z-index` for the `.welcome` class must be greater.
2. Use the `position: absolute;` property.
3. The `left: 0; right: 0;` properties makes the block as wide as the screen.

Please check the result: https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/fc8aydb4/

```css
@import url('https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css');

body{
  padding-top: 87px;
}

.welcome {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  top: 5px;
  z-index: 2000;
}
.welcome h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">   
    <button class="hamburger hamburger--collapse hamburger--accessible js-hamburger" type="button">
        <span class="hamburger-box">
            <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
        </span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#home" id="menuhome">Accueil</a></li>
            <li><a href="#osteo" id="menuosteo">L'ostéopathie</a></li>
            <li><a href="#parcours" id="menuparcours">Mon parcours</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact" id="menucontact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="welcome">
    <h1>Bienvenue</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: But now there is another problem, the <li><a></a></li> are not clickable anymore because of the z-index ...

Comment: @Nathan30 I've updated my answer. Please check the second version of the code.